# htaccess redirect all except multiple folders and files

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have been trying multiple different type of example but I cant get it work when trying to add more folder and file as the exception for redirection. I just know this one example could work in my apache localhost:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  !^js($|/) http://google.com [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

So basically I want to redirect all except js,css,img folders and getOrder.php, getCustomer.php files, something like that. Could anyone help in this case?

Comment: Do you *actually* want to redirect anything that doesn't exist?

Comment: I want to redirect everything except those folders and files, if someone access other folder or file than I specify in the htaccess like cookies.txt or any other , redirect them. The above code I put only allow js access, when trying to add more, it failed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add a "last" rule that says "Don;t touch these folders". Then do your redirect after that.

Edit: Updated answer with the wrapper elements (FollowSymLink, ReWriteEngine on).

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

# These folders will not be touched.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/css/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/img/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

# Then have your redirect rule
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  (.*) http://google.com [L,R=301]
```

---

Although as suggested in the comments, you can have a redirect on "file not found" which may be more appropriate? Or put a redirect in the folders you don;t want someone to read. It's also nicer to redirect to a page on your saying saying "Not Found" than to redirect to google too. But that's your call.

Comment: Iam not sure but your example didn't work, I still can access those css and img folder without redirection to google. But if you said file is not found(nonexist), there is no need to do anything about that right?

Comment: The htaccess allows you to access the CSS and image folders - isn't that what you asked for? The folders (or files) listed are those that you don't redirect to.

Comment: I meant, it can still access all folders, not just css and img folder. How about file, are you using REQUEST_FILENAME something like that?

Comment: @Ardeus I've updated answer with the wrapper elements (FollowSymLink, ReWriteEngine on). Sorry - I took them as a given. It definately works as I've tested (and tested again!)